# Sort on amount of likes on facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a site with a bunch of links, the page is also connected to facebook (facebook connect) and you can "like" the links. I wonder if there is a way to sort on the "most liked" link? The links are stored in my database and of course the liking is stored by Facebook...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with liking links, but perhaps you can query the `link_stat` table. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat

Comment: Sadly i have to send in urls to that method, i wonder if there could be some other query to call

Answer (score 1):

Here is an even easier method to get likes. It doesn't require that you are logged in to Facebook. I have also made an example of how you can sort them. In PHP though.. :-/
http://www.sundh.com/blog/2010/11/get-likes-on-urls-from-facebook/

Comment: That also requires me to send in all the urls of my site to this service.  Would be better to be able to send in a domain and get all the likes on all the subpages. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should retrieve your links' Likes Count from facebook by sending url's or by FQL, etc
2. Store "liking" count in your urls table
3. Sort your links table ORDER BY -linkcountfield- DESC